# Pandas: create a new dataframe from existing with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new dataframe from [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZZBX.png) with two conditions:
**sex == "Male" & "age" > 35**

So I have used this code:

```
df_work = df[(df.age > 35) & (df.sex == 'Male')]
```

But that does not work: [I have empty one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36qb3.png)

Moreover I have tried this code:

```
df_work = df[(df['age'] > 35) & (df['sex'] == 'Male')]
```

But I have the same problem - that`s empty. How can I solve it?

I use this:

- Python 3.8.5
- Pandas 1.2.3
- Jupyter Notebook
- Linux Ubuntu 20.04

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Check the `dtype` of column `age`. Mostly it is `object`. You need to convert it to `int` first. Try `df_work = df[(df.age.astype(int) > 35) & (df.sex == 'Male')]` .

Comment: The dtype of age column was int64 - I`ve cheked this with df.info() command. So I have tried your code but the problem is the same: df_work [is empty](https://ibb.co/nQ2qHsL) :(

Comment: Ok. Then please check the values of `df.sex`. Does it have spaces also? Try with `df.sex.values`.

Comment: Oh. There are spaces before so the values after `df.sex.unique()` are: `array([' Male', ' Female'], dtype=object)`. Thanks you a lot! <3